# How to query Azure DocumentDB with an equivalent of the SELECT DISTINCT statement

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

DocumentDb don't support the `DISTINCT` statement. I have documents in DocumentDB with the following structure (thousands of documents):

```
{
    "type" : "type1",
    "data" : {
        ...
    }
},{
    "type" : "type2",
    "data" : {
        ...
    }
},{
    "type" : "type2",
    "data" : {
        ...
    }
},{
    "type" : "type2",
    "data" : {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I query the collection and get the following result:

```
{
    "type" : "type1"
},{
    "type" : "type2"
}
```

Comment: Do you want the query to return just "type" attribute from your collection or distinct types?

Comment: I want the query to return distinct types.

Comment: Short answer is: You can't get it in an efficient way. Long one:
You can create trigger on insert which would create collection with distinct types and another on delete to check if this document was the last of this type to remove. But that is just a workaround. Why do you need this distinct type? For suggestions, filtering or something else?

Comment: Thanks @plentysmart Maybe your workaround is the closest I get. The reason why I want this; I got 150-200 _types_ of documents and want to display some kind of statuslist representing available _types_ in the collection. By available, I mean types already in the collection.

Comment: This workaround is far from perfect and has limitations. You would have to keep "collection" of your distinct types in the same DocumentDB collection due to transaction scope (single collection) which might get messy. If you don't need strong consistency I would probably go for some external "indexing" and keep it in sync though domain events (document created/modified/deleted).

Comment: To see this feature included in future plans, please vote for it;
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6719531-provide-support-for-distinct

Answer (score 7):

Azure DocumentDB currently does not support `DISTINCT`.

Please voice your opinion and vote for this feature on [DocumentDB's feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6719531-provide-support-for-distinct).