# Azure DocumentDB get partition key values in collection

Tags: c#, python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'd like to fetch all PartitionKey values in a Collection.

Read collections in Database is achieved by `client.ReadCollections(database_link)` but I cannot find similar to `ReadPartitions` in [documentation](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-python/api/pydocumentdb.document_client.html) and [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/Partitioning/Program.cs).

And, I thought querying unique values of partitionkey property could be helpful, but [DISTINCT is not available in DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26928950/361100).

Is it possible? I prefer Python SDK, but other approaches are welcomed.

Comment: There can be only one partition key per collection

Comment: @GopiKolla // oh! thanks. I edited question; is it possible to get partition values in given partition key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to retrieve the values for the partition key, for example, using a `"SELECT c.partitionKey FROM c ORDER BY c.partitionKey"`, then performing a Distinct client side by ignoring duplicate value, since DISTINCT is not supported natively in DocumentDB.